# Can you 'require' components/UI elements multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am looking to write a certain View for my application, it will have 2 buttons, a Text Label. The buttons will increment and decrement the Text Label.

I am hoping that I can re-use the View multiple times, but each time I use the View, it will have a different use. So each time I can pass in new variables, the buttons can increment/decrement the value and then it can be passed back to a Data Store or something similar.

Can I re-use Views written once, multiple times? Are there any good resources/docs for code re-use with React Native?

Comment: I think this is more a fundamental question about React. The way you can reuse components with different variables is through props and passing them into the components.  One of the great things about React is the ability to reuse components exactly the way you are asking about, but I don't think there is enough room to go into everything. I would refer you to the React documentation, as well as suggest maybe taking some tutorials either on Egghead.io or Pluralsight that go into the fundamentals of React.

Comment: What you ask is pure fundemental stuff a react application can handle, you can manipulate data pass to a component through state and props. You always write single View which being rerender as long the data given is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Nader, this is a generic react question and his suggestion to check out an Egghead.io course is a good one. Here's a quick 4 minute video I think addresses your immediate question though....

### [React Composable Components](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-composable-components)

https://egghead.io/lessons/react-composable-components